# paypal php sdk returns getSupplementaryDataMap() missing

Tags: php, paypal

I was using the paypal sdk for over a year without a problem and everything was working great but now for some reason the same code it returns this error

`Method PayPal\Api\Transaction::getSupplementaryDataMap() does not exist`

This is returned from paypal.

I look everywhere for this function and there is such function anywhere. I even download new version of the php SDK and there wasn't function like this there as well.

Answer (score 1):

We had same issue 3 days ago. Updating PayPal SDK to v1.6.4 fixed the issue.

Comment: This was my turning point to go with stripe. Much easy to implement and use!